# In Postgres current_timestamp behaves differently called from function vs called from a sql statement

Tags: postgresql

I noticed a strange behavior with current_timestamp on Postgres

I have  a java server in CET and db server in UTC.

From the db server if I run **select current_timestamp** from a statement it returns time in CET
If I call a function doing the same thing using a CallableStatement it returns time in UTC

Is this difference expected ? (I expected to have both return time in CET) is there a way to configure the function to behave like the sql statement ?

Comment: current_timestamp is of type timestamptz - so its always inserted as UTC.

Comment: *select current_timestamp*  executed from my java server (CET) return time in CET, and *select current_timestamp* from the db server (UTC) return time in UTC so it is converted into caller timezone somehow

Comment: it shows you your according to your client `TimeZone`, but saves always in UTC

Comment: I save it in a timestamp without timezone column, so timezone is lost let's say it is 10 am UTC on my db server and 11 am CET on my java server, the *insert select current_timestamp* insert 11 am executed from my java server and insert 10 am executed from a function. I can simplify my question

Comment: so if you save timestamptz to timestamp without tz the result will depend on your clients - adjust both java and other client to have same TimeZone and you will have same results

Comment: I understand that and It is what I did, I have no issues, I just want to understand if it is expected that from the very same client, calling from inside a function behaves differently, than calling the code outside in a regular sql statement (if yes eventually to know if there is a way to tell the function to behave like sql stament for this)

Comment: you can set different TimeZone on transaction level, but not on statement - soit should not matter if you insert in function or in one statement